# Odd issue while reading checkbox state

Tags: checkbox

I have a checkbox column in a datagridview.When I try to iterate through the column,the results vary on each iteration despite no changes in the checkboxes.The following is the code:

> Dim TotalRows As Integer = 0
>
> ```
>         For RW As Integer = 0 To DGVMulyo.Rows.Count - 1
>             MsgBox(DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).Value)
>             If DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).Value = True Then
>                 TotalRows = TotalRows + 1
>             End If
>         Next
> ```

On each iteration of the loop,the messagebox will show differing results of the state of the checkboxes.Some times even if the checkbox is checked,the output is shown as 0.
I also tried the following but the same issue persisted:

> ```
>         For RW As Integer = 0 To DGVMulyo.Rows.Count - 1
>             MsgBox(DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).State)
>             If DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).State = True Then
>                 TotalRows = TotalRows + 1
>             End If
>         Next
> ```

In the end,the following code seems to work reliably:

> Dim TotalRows As Integer = 0
>
> ```
>         For RW As Integer = 0 To DGVMulyo.Rows.Count - 1
>             'MsgBox(DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).Value)
>             If DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).Value = True Or DGVMulyo.Rows(RW).Cells(1).Value = 1 Then
>                 TotalRows = TotalRows + 1
>             End If
>             '  MsgBox(TotalRows)
>         Next
> ```

I am using VS-2017 Community edition with Windows-7 32 Bit OS.

Khalid.

Comment: It seems you've already solved your problem. What is your question?

Comment: Problem is solved but why should I even need to use two conditions of True or 1 to get a reliable report.Normally only of these two is sufficient to get the correct result.Is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: We'd need to know more about your data in your cells to answer that question.

Comment: How would the data in other cells/rows affect the result of a scan of the checkbox column.The checkbox column does not have any other data.
However,I suspect that another action of mine might have resulted in this strange problem.I have written a code wherein,just by clicking in the row of an adjacent column,the checkbox of that row gets checked.That is,I set it to True.This might be the reason that those checkboxes which have been checked by setting to True are returning True and those checked directly are returning a value of 1.